# How do I set up a function to convert vector of strings to vector of integers in VC++?

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, vector

The question is in the title. Need help figuring out why my code compiles but doesn't work as intended. Thanks!

```
//This example demonstrates how to do vector<string> to vectro<int> conversion using a function.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

vector<int>* convertStringVectorToIntVector (vector<string> *vectorOfStrings)
{
    vector<int> *vectorOfIntegers = new vector<int>;
    int x;
    for (int i=0; i<vectorOfStrings->size(); i++)
    {
        stringstream str(vectorOfStrings->at(i));
        str >> x;
        vectorOfIntegers->push_back(x);
    }
    return vectorOfIntegers;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    //Initialize test vector to use for conversion
    vector<string> *vectorOfStringTypes = new vector<string>();
    vectorOfStringTypes->push_back("1"); 
    vectorOfStringTypes->push_back("10"); 
    vectorOfStringTypes->push_back("100");
    delete vectorOfStringTypes;

    //Initialize target vector to store conversion result
    vector<int> *vectorOfIntTypes;
    vectorOfIntTypes = convertStringVectorToIntVector(vectorOfStringTypes);

    //Test if conversion is successful and the new vector is open for manipulation
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<vectorOfIntTypes->size(); i++)
    {
        sum+=vectorOfIntTypes->at(i);
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    }
    delete vectorOfIntTypes;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code above has only one problem:  You are deleting your vectorOfStringTypes before you pass it to your conversion function.

Move the line `delete vectorOfStringTypes;` to after you have called your convert function and the program works as intended.